# Image and file operations on Android

Tags: java, android, image, file, uri

I get pictures url from gallery or camera on android but I can't convert them to file. When i developing an app with Java in android, sometimes I need to get pictures from gallery and camera to my application. But when i try to do this I'm getting errors.
Isn't there a standard here? The code works at one api level and does not works another one. Or when I take the URI of some images and convert it to file, I get an error regardless of the api level. I wonder if there is a fundamental solution to this problem?

I am starting intent with this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(intent,IMAGE_RESULT);
```

And then I'm catching data with this code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_RESULT) {
            String filePath = ImageFilePath.getPath(OwnProfileActivity.this, data.getData());
            selectedFile = new File(filePath);
            showProgressDialog();
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(this::chaneProfileImage, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you try something, do you have something to show, some code? like this can be easier to help you

Comment: @Azhagthott I'm sorry. I edited my question

Comment: Why would you try to convert an Uri to a File instance? There mostly is no reason to do so.

Comment: I am using Parse server and i should change the profile picture. In parse server profile picture's type is parse file. So i have to send this picture as type file to the server.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest something like this, but of course this is if you have a bitmap:

```
private fun getImageUriFromBitmap(image: Bitmap): Uri? {
val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes)   

val relativeLocation = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.pathSeparator + "NotifyMe"
val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "notifyMe_${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png")
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relativeLocation)            
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 1)
    }
}
return context?.contentResolver?.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
}
```

Then you can create the file with the uri

```
val file = File(uri.path)
```

source: https://gist.github.com/franciscobarrios/9f6634c87ca6e56ed70cd96807dd1dcb

Comment: Thanks for answer but i don't have a bitmap, Intent sending me a data (type of Intent) and I am taking the uri from that data